# knex generate schemas from existing database

Tags: javascript, orm, knex.js

I have an existing database, I'd like to use knex.js query builder with. The database is readonly for my purposes, I will only be performing selects.

I don't want to create or seed the database or do any migrations, just connect to it. I do not want to hand create all the schemas for every table.

Is there a way or utility to generate the schema files/data model from an existing database?